# Start css animation only when button clicked for multiple div overlapping each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few different content(div) overlapping each other in one place. I wanted to have a fade in animation when i click the trigger to show the desired content. But the animation is only play when the page is onload and would never play again if i trigger another content.
HTML code:

```
  <div id="content">
  <div class="content1 sq" id="square"></div>
  <div class="content2 sq" id="square"></div>
  <div class="content3 sq" id="square"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS code:

```
#square{
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fade 3s linear;
}

@keyframes fade{
  0% {opacity: 0}
  100% {opacity: 1}

}
```

Javascript:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sq");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("click");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.visibility = "hidden";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.visibility = "visible";

}
```

The code showed above is not the full code as the button to change to different content is through a SVG.
Please refer the link for the full code.
https://codepen.io/lemon55699/pen/bGVrMXz

Comment: Start with removing same id, ID should be unique and not meant to use twice or trice on same page

Comment: I have seen your codepen, you just want to change the color of the rectangle on click of SVG item? right?

Comment: @Atul Yes. But not exactly i might want to change the color to images or text in the future but now im currently using color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to change the background color on click, then just get the fill color from clicked item and then apply the same background color on your square. like this.

```js
let circles = gsap.utils.toArray([".c1", ".c2", ".c3", ".c4", ".c5", ".c6", ".c7", ".c8", ".c9"]),
    angleIncrement = 360 / circles.length;


circles.forEach(function(circle, index) {

  circle.addEventListener("click", function() {

    gsap.to(".wheel", {
      rotation: (index * angleIncrement) + "_short", 
      duration: 1,
      ease: "power1.inOut"
    });
  });
});

 
let bounds = document.querySelector(".st0").getBBox();
gsap.set(".wheel", {svgOrigin: (bounds.x + bounds.width / 2) + " " + (bounds.y + bounds.height / 2)});



var slideIndex = 1;
// showDivs(slideIndex);

// function currentDiv() {
//   var element = this,
//     style = getComputedStyle(element),
//     top = style.getPropertyValue('color');
    
// }
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.click').click(function(){
    var bgColor = $(this).css('fill');
    $('#square').css('background-color' , bgColor);
  });
});
```

```css
#Layer_1 {width: 25%; height: 25%; padding-top: 20px; position: relative;}
#fixed{fill:none;stroke: #000000;stroke-width:2;}
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:#00FFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st2{fill:#0000FF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st3{fill:#FF00FF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st4{fill:#C1272D;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st5{fill:#ED1C24;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st6{fill:#F15A24;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st7{fill:#FF0000;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st8{fill:#FFFF00;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st9{fill:#00FF00;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}

.content1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  fill: green;
  background-color: green;

}
.content2{
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  background-color: yellow;

}
.content3{
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 70px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  background-color: red;

}

#square{
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fade 3s linear;
}

@keyframes fade{
  0% {opacity: 0}
  100% {opacity: 1}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js"></script>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 470 467" style="enable-background:new 0 0 470 467;" xml:space="preserve">
  <g class="wheel">
   <path class="st0" d="M304,234c0,12.2-3.26,23.64-8.97,33.5c-1.96,3.39-4.21,6.59-6.7,9.57c-7.5,8.92-17.27,15.85-28.41,19.9
    c-3.62,1.32-7.4,2.34-11.28,3.02c-3.78,0.66-7.68,1.01-11.64,1.01c-8.05,0-15.77-1.42-22.92-4.03c-3.69-1.34-7.23-3-10.58-4.95
    c-10.17-5.87-18.65-14.35-24.53-24.52c-1.94-3.35-3.6-6.89-4.94-10.58c-2.61-7.15-4.03-14.87-4.03-22.92
    c0-3.97,0.34-7.85,1.01-11.63c0.68-3.89,1.7-7.66,3.02-11.29c4.05-11.15,10.99-20.92,19.9-28.4c2.98-2.51,6.18-4.76,9.57-6.71
    c9.85-5.71,21.29-8.97,33.5-8.97c3.97,0,7.86,0.34,11.64,1.01c11.83,2.07,22.6,7.25,31.43,14.67c2.99,2.51,5.75,5.27,8.25,8.26
    c7.42,8.83,12.6,19.59,14.67,31.43C303.66,226.15,304,230.03,304,234z"/>
   <g id="stick9">
    <line id="wheel" class="st1" x1="332.76" y1="314.35" x2="288.33" y2="277.07"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st1 c9 click" cx="371.06" cy="346.49" r="50"/>
   </g>
   <g id="stick8">
    <line id="wheel" class="st2" x1="258.71" y1="357.1" x2="248.64" y2="299.99"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st2 c8 click" cx="267.39" cy="406.34" r="50"/>
   </g>
   <g id="stick7">
    <line id="wheel" class="st3" x1="203.5" y1="292.02" x2="174.5" y2="342.25"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st3 c7 click" cx="149.5" cy="385.55" r="50"/>
   </g>
   <g id="stick6">
    <line id="wheel" class="st4" x1="174.03" y1="256.92" x2="119.54" y2="276.75"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st4 c6 click" cx="72.55" cy="293.85" r="50"/>
   </g>
   <g id="stick5">
    <line id="wheel" class="st5" x1="174.03" y1="211.08" x2="119.54" y2="191.25"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st5 c5 click" cx="72.55" cy="174.15" r="50"/>
   </g>
   <g>
    <line id="wheel" class="st6" x1="203.5" y1="175.97" x2="174.5" y2="125.75"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st6 c4 click" cx="149.5" cy="82.45" r="50"/>
   </g>
   <g id="stick3">
    <line id="wheel" class="st7" x1="258.71" y1="110.9" x2="248.64" y2="168.01"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st7 c3 click" cx="267.39" cy="61.66" r="50" >
   </g>
   <g id="stick2">
    <line id="wheel" class="st8" x1="332.76" y1="153.65" x2="288.32" y2="190.94"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st8 c2 click" cx="371.06" cy="121.51" r="50" />
   </g>
   <g id="stick1">
    <line id="wheel" class="st9" x1="362" y1="234" x2="304" y2="234"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st9 c1 click" cx="412" cy="234" r="50" />
   </g>
  </g>

</svg>

<div id="content">
  <div class="content1 sq" id="square"></div>
</div>
```

but as you mentined in comment, if you want to change the whole square with its properties and text and other stuff, then do it something like this, you need to create a relation between the clicked item and the square box, and show only reated item and not others. Like this,

```js
let circles = gsap.utils.toArray([".c1", ".c2", ".c3", ".c4", ".c5", ".c6", ".c7", ".c8", ".c9"]),
    angleIncrement = 360 / circles.length;


circles.forEach(function(circle, index) {

  circle.addEventListener("click", function() {

    gsap.to(".wheel", {
      rotation: (index * angleIncrement) + "_short", 
      duration: 1,
      ease: "power1.inOut"
    });
  });
});

 
let bounds = document.querySelector(".st0").getBBox();
gsap.set(".wheel", {svgOrigin: (bounds.x + bounds.width / 2) + " " + (bounds.y + bounds.height / 2)});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.circle').click(function(){
    var relation = $(this).data('relation');
    var squareReltedToClick = $("#content").find('#' + relation);
    $('.sq').removeClass('active');
    squareReltedToClick.addClass('active');
    var bgColor = $(this).css('fill');
    $('.sq').css('background-color', bgColor);
  });
});
```

```css
#Layer_1 {width: 25%; height: 25%; padding-top: 20px; position: relative;}
#fixed{fill:none;stroke: #000000;stroke-width:2;}
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:#00FFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st2{fill:#0000FF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st3{fill:#FF00FF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st4{fill:#C1272D;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st5{fill:#ED1C24;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st6{fill:#F15A24;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st7{fill:#FF0000;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st8{fill:#FFFF00;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st9{fill:#00FF00;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}

.sq{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 90px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  fill: green;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  opacity: 0;
text-align:center;
  color: #fff;
font-size: 40px;
}
.sq.active {opacity:1;}

.sq.active{
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fade 3s linear;
}

@keyframes fade{
  0% {opacity: 0}
  100% {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 470 467" style="enable-background:new 0 0 470 467;" xml:space="preserve">
  <g class="wheel">
   <path class="st0" d="M304,234c0,12.2-3.26,23.64-8.97,33.5c-1.96,3.39-4.21,6.59-6.7,9.57c-7.5,8.92-17.27,15.85-28.41,19.9
    c-3.62,1.32-7.4,2.34-11.28,3.02c-3.78,0.66-7.68,1.01-11.64,1.01c-8.05,0-15.77-1.42-22.92-4.03c-3.69-1.34-7.23-3-10.58-4.95
    c-10.17-5.87-18.65-14.35-24.53-24.52c-1.94-3.35-3.6-6.89-4.94-10.58c-2.61-7.15-4.03-14.87-4.03-22.92
    c0-3.97,0.34-7.85,1.01-11.63c0.68-3.89,1.7-7.66,3.02-11.29c4.05-11.15,10.99-20.92,19.9-28.4c2.98-2.51,6.18-4.76,9.57-6.71
    c9.85-5.71,21.29-8.97,33.5-8.97c3.97,0,7.86,0.34,11.64,1.01c11.83,2.07,22.6,7.25,31.43,14.67c2.99,2.51,5.75,5.27,8.25,8.26
    c7.42,8.83,12.6,19.59,14.67,31.43C303.66,226.15,304,230.03,304,234z"/>
   <g id="stick9">
    <line id="wheel" class="st1" x1="332.76" y1="314.35" x2="288.33" y2="277.07"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st1 c9 circle" data-relation="square9" cx="371.06" cy="346.49" r="50"/>
   </g>
   <g id="stick8">
    <line id="wheel" class="st2" x1="258.71" y1="357.1" x2="248.64" y2="299.99"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st2 c8 circle" data-relation="square8" cx="267.39" cy="406.34" r="50"/>
   </g>
   <g id="stick7">
    <line id="wheel" class="st3" x1="203.5" y1="292.02" x2="174.5" y2="342.25"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st3 c7 circle" data-relation="square7" cx="149.5" cy="385.55" r="50"/>
   </g>
   <g id="stick6">
    <line id="wheel" class="st4" x1="174.03" y1="256.92" x2="119.54" y2="276.75"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st4 c6 circle" data-relation="square6" cx="72.55" cy="293.85" r="50"/>
   </g>
   <g id="stick5">
    <line id="wheel" class="st5" x1="174.03" y1="211.08" x2="119.54" y2="191.25"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st5 c5 circle" data-relation="square5" cx="72.55" cy="174.15" r="50"/>
   </g>
   <g>
    <line id="wheel" class="st6" x1="203.5" y1="175.97" x2="174.5" y2="125.75"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st6 c4 circle" data-relation="square4" cx="149.5" cy="82.45" r="50"/>
   </g>
   <g id="stick3">
    <line id="wheel" class="st7" x1="258.71" y1="110.9" x2="248.64" y2="168.01"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st7 c3 circle" data-relation="square3" cx="267.39" cy="61.66" r="50"/>
   </g>
   <g id="stick2">
    <line id="wheel" class="st8" x1="332.76" y1="153.65" x2="288.32" y2="190.94"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st8 c2 circle" data-relation="square2" cx="371.06" cy="121.51" r="50"/>
   </g>
   <g id="stick1">
    <line id="wheel" class="st9" x1="362" y1="234" x2="304" y2="234"/>
    <circle id="wheel" class="st9 c1 circle" data-relation="square1" cx="412" cy="234" r="50" />
   </g>
  </g>

</svg>

<div id="content">
  <div class="content1 sq active" id="square1">I am number 1</div>
  <div class="content2 sq" id="square2">I am number 2</div>
  <div class="content3 sq" id="square3">I am number 3</div>
  <div class="content4 sq" id="square4">I am number 4</div>
  <div class="content5 sq" id="square5">I am number 5</div>
  <div class="content6 sq" id="square6">I am number 6</div>
  <div class="content7 sq" id="square7">I am number 7</div>
  <div class="content8 sq" id="square8">I am number 8</div>
  <div class="content9 sq" id="square9">I am number 9</div>
</div>
```

I have changed some CSS properties for demo purpose, change these as per your need.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If i wanted to use the data relation method, can i animate the inside of the content with gasp? Let say if i have multiple square boxes inside one of the content and i want to make them rotate or slide in.

Comment: you can animate what ever you want with Gsap, apply right logic and function only